# Formatting XML tags for XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, awk, sed, vlc

I'm attempting to style an XML file using XSLT.  I've a BASH shell script that uses the WGET command to  download a copy of the XML file from VLC Media Player once every 5 seconds.  Below is an example section of the XML file that contains the information I'd like to style with XSLT.  Notice in the example XML, there are numerous tags that start with <info name='*unique*'> and ends with </info>.  For example, the first tag is <info name='date'>1991</info> and the third tag is <info name='filename'>Something in the Way</info>.

```
<category name="meta">
<info name='date'>1991</info>
<info name='artwork_url'>file://D:/Music/Nirvana/Nevermind/Folder.jpg</info>
<info name='filename'>Something in the Way</info>  </category>
```

I'm using this code in the head of the XML file to style the XML.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
```

When I bring up the .xml file in a browser, it is styled via the XSLT.  However, only the first <info> tag is displayed.  In this example, only <info name='date'>1991</info> would be displayed.  My overall objective is to display only the bandname and songname in the browser.

I actually have what I think is a very unusual solution, which would be to use the **SED** or **AWK** Command in Linux in conjunction with some type of auto_increment option, to find and replace the text info so that the XML is transformed into something like the below.  I could then setup the XSLT to read info1, info2, info3, et cetera.

```
<info1>data</info1>
<info2>data</info2>
<info3>data</info3>
```

It is difficult to accomplish this unusual workaround, because VLC outputs dynamic info tags, so one XML file might have the <info name='date'> tag, and the next XML file might not contain the <info name='date'> tag, so I can't use the AWK command that expects $27 to always be <info name='date'>.  This also seems like it can't be the recommended solution to this issue, and is probably a volatile method, which is why I'm posting the question here for feedback.

I did also do some research into XML namespacing, but I wasn't quite sure if I should be focusing on namespacing here.  Any insight, tips or recommendations would be very much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Title</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="category">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="info"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can use any attribute name you want in your `select="info"` line.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation @Jongware!  Let's say my XML has 
<info name='date'>1991
</info> and 
<info name='bandname'>Nirvana
</info>.  In my XSLT stylesheet, 
<xsl:value-of select="info"/> will display 1991 in the browser.  I've tried other variations. If I try 
<xsl:value-of select="bandname"/>, the browser doesn't display any data.  If I try 
<xsl:value-of select="info name='bandname' "/>, the browser throws an xpath error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, `xsl:value-of` gets the value of the first node of the selected node-set. If you want to get all of them, use something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="category">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="info">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, you can pick them individually by their `name` attribute, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="category">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="info[@name='date']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="info[@name='filename']"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or by their position:

```
<xsl:for-each select="category">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="info[1]"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="info[3]"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Awesome, Awesome, Awesome!!!  Thanks so much @michael.hor257k.  I really appreciate it.